# Get file from GCS and load to bigquery based on file name pattern

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, wildcard

We have requirement of loading file from gcs bucket to different bigquery table based on file name pattern.
eg

```
bucket/folder/test_a_20221023.csv  -> should go to table a
bucket/folder/file_a_20221023_2.csv  -> should go to table a
bucket/folder/control_b_20221023.csv  -> should go to table b
bucket/folder/test_b_20221023_2.csv  -> should go to table b
```

So prefix can be anything before a or b pattern in the filename and based on a or b we have to load to specific table in bigquery. Is there any way to get the file in gcs based on some pattern other than gsutil command

```
gsutil ls gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/** | grep string
```

Comment: I have an article similar to your question https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-cloud-workflows-to-load-cloud-storage-files-into-bigquery-54228d166a7d

Comment: Hi OP. Let us know if the answer helped. If it's useful, consider upvoting it. If it answered your question, then please accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach you can consider is by using a Python script. Basically, the logic would be to:

1. [List the objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) in your bucket or folder and sort it according to their category or group.
2. [Create a loop and use the `load_table_from_uri` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery_load_table_partitioned-python) to load data according to the lists created from step 1.

Here is a sample code based on your use case:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
import re

def list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix, delimiter=None):

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter)

    a_list = []
    b_list = []
    for blob in blobs:
        is_a = re.search("\w+\/\w+_a_\d+\_?\d+?.csv", blob.name)
        is_b = re.search("\w+\/\w+_b_\d+\_?\d+?.csv", blob.name)
        if is_a:
            a_list.append(f'gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}')
        elif is_b:
            b_list.append(f'gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}')

    return a_list,b_list

def load_to_bq():
    bucket_name="your-bucket"
    prefix="folder/"

    table_a = "PROJECT_ID.dataset.gcs_csv_a"
    table_b = "PROJECT_ID.dataset.gcs_csv_b"

    a_list,b_list = list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix,delimiter="/")

    client = bigquery.Client()

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        autodetect=True,
        skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    )

    for csv_file_a in a_list:
        load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
                csv_file_a, table_a, job_config=job_config
                )
        load_job.result()

    for csv_file_b in b_list:
        load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
                csv_file_b, table_b, job_config=job_config
                )
        load_job.result()

load_to_bq()
```

```
Folder structure: gs://bucket_name/folder/control_b_20221023.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to you use a BATCH DataFlow to make this, maybe it's gonna be necessary learn how to use a Apache-beam[GCP] or you can try use a DEFAULT Dataflow that make this, but I don't think he gonna respect the name files